# form keeps getting submit event without pressing submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a form so when user click button then it will submit but the problem is that it is keep getting on function even if I am not pressing submit button. here is my code

```
$(function () {
var url, container, form,
    View = {
        init: function () {
            container   = $('.container');
            form        = $('.search#form');
            console.log(form);
            View.loadViews();
            $(document).on('submit', '#form', View.findView());
        },
        findView: function () {
            console.log('helllo');
            return false;
        },
        loadViews: function (view) {
            $(container).load('search.html');
        }
    };
View.init();
});
```

In code above the line `$(document).on('submit', '#form', View.findView());` keeps calling findView() method whereas I want to call it when user click submit button. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bind it using `$(document).on('submit', '#form', View.findView());`, you are essentially calling the function and trying to bind the submit event to what the function returns, which is incorrect. Since `findView()` is returning `false`, this is equivalent of saying `$(document).on('submit', '#form', false);`

You need to bind `View.findView()` like below:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', View.findView); // note, no () at the end
```

Comment: That *might* work. It depends on how `findView` is written. If it depends on `this` being `View`, it will break.

Comment: @Quentin - Here i think `View` is treated more like a static singleton which is not instantiated explicitly at all, so `this` will likely not picture here. But yes, it is something to be careful about.

Comment: Note to self: Read the question more carefully. You're right, this will work (unless the code in the question has been over simplified).

Answer (score 1):

you should pass reference of function not function returned value.

`$(document).on('submit', '#form', View.findView);`